# How can I test if a callback closure has been called?

Tags: rust

Consider my struct `WareHouse` which has a `watch` function which takes a closure as an argument.

The struct also has an `update` function which updates a path and a value, and should then call the closure passed into the `watch` function if applicable.

How can I verify that when I call `watch(callback)` followed by an update the callback function is triggered?

I tried:

```
#[test]
fn calls_watcher_on_update() {
    let mut w = WareHouse::new();
    let mut called = false;
    // set a watcher 
    w.watch(move|| {
        println!("watcher called");
        called = true;
    });
    w.update("/foo", "baz").unwrap();
    assert!(called);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to move a value that implements `Copy`, it is copied instead. So your closure captures the value of `called` the moment that it was created; `called` within and outside of the closure are effectively two different variables.

You should even be getting a warning on this, something like:

```
warning: value captured by `called` is never read
```

Instead, consider capturing a `Cell<bool>` by reference.  I'm inferring that you need a `Cell` here because capturing by mutable reference would require that `w` drop the closure before you can read the value in `assert!()` or you would get a "cannot borrow mutably while already borrowed" error.

```
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    // Doesn't work right; called is copied into the closure, not moved.
    {
        let mut called = false;
        let mut closure = move || {
            called = true;
            println!("(A) In closure, called is {called}");
        };
        closure();
        println!("(A) Outside of closure, called is {called}");
    }
    
    // Workes correctly; the closure captures a reference to the cell.
    {
        let called = Cell::new(false);
        let closure = || {
            called.set(true);
            println!("(B) In closure, called is {}", called.get());
        };
        closure();
        println!("(B) Outside of closure, called is {}", called.get());
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
(A) In closure, called is true
(A) Outside of closure, called is false
(B) In closure, called is true
(B) Outside of closure, called is true
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fbe174a33cc4826e6c5ba38cd399c0fa))

Answer (score 2):

A different way would be to encapsulate the `called` status into your `Warehouse` struct. If you need that value to follow your struct around as it's passed to functions or something, this will handle that without needing to track multiple variables:

```rust
struct Warehouse {
    callback: Option<fn() -> ()>,
    called: bool,
}

impl Warehouse {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            callback: None,
            called: false,
        }
    }

    fn watch(&mut self, f: fn() -> ()) {
        self.callback = Some(f);
    }

    fn update(&mut self, path: &str, value: &str) -> Result<(), ()> {
        if let Some(cb) = self.callback {
            cb();
            self.called = true;
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(())
        }
    }

    fn was_called(&self) -> bool {
        self.called
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut w = Warehouse::new();
    // set a watcher
    w.watch(move|| {
        println!("watcher called");
    });

    // updates *and* calls the closure
    w.update("/foo", "baz").unwrap();
    
    // getter method to see if it was called (could also be pub member)
    assert!(w.was_called());
}
```

Comment: `called` is a unit test artifact. Moving it out of the test code doesn't seem right.

Comment: I didn’t pick up that it was only used for testing, but in that case, yeah this makes less sense.